# How can I detect if a user is invisible on Yahoo Messenger

Tags: api, yahoo-messenger

There are some existing online services (like [this one](http://detectinvisible.com/)) where you can enter a yahoo user, and it will tell you if the user is online, invisible or offline.

Is there a way I can do that? (using some Yahoo API? or using some tricks?)

**Note:** The programming language doesn't matter too much. It could be Python, C#, etc.

Comment: @DanielA.White to be honest, the only thing I've tried (apart from reading) is scraping one of the pages that already does that, and of course, that's not what I'm after.

Comment: I don't really understand why this is **not a real question**.